# Recycle custom error log

Tags: php, .htaccess, logging, error-handling

I am logging errors for my site like this in my htaccess

`php_flag log_errors off
php_value error_log /usr/home/example/phplog/errors.txt`

I understand it is a good practice to limit the file size of the log or recycle it but don't know how. I tried goggling it but all I found was how you can rotate the default access or error logs not a custom one like mine.

Please help!

Thx

Answer (score 0):

OK, did a lot of digging but here is what I found and makes a lot of sense.

The apache php_flag instructions do not have anything for limiting the size of a log file, only the individual log entries. So the way we can around the problem is through CRON JOBS. I could have a nightly script run that archives the previous day's log file. Hope this helps someone.